# Where to post a Fluid Power Systems/Mechatronic Engineering question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Which StackExchange forum (if any) would be the best to post on? There doesn't seem to be a general Engineering forum and most of the Engineering forums that are there are [closed].

Comment: There will soon be an [Engineering.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60453/engineering) beta site. And by soon, I mean anytime from 6 hours to 8 weeks. I would advise you to commit to that proposal so that you can participate in the private beta.

Comment: Thanks Sompuperoo, I'll hang around for a few hours ..see what happens : ]

Comment: I must say, I'm a little shocked that there isn't an Engineering.SE site set up already!? Type of site that you would just expect to be there..

Comment: @stevesy [It's up.](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/)